# How to get a part of the levels of a categorical variable?

Tags: r

My data set looks like the following:

```
        dsn                register_at
1 AC000W000014612   Thu Mar 02 21:34:30 UTC 2017
2 AC000W000016124   Tue Mar 14 19:40:57 UTC 2017
3 AC000W000016219   Tue Apr 14 19:29:10 UTC 2017
```

I need to get just the month specification like Mar, Apr etc for each dsn. How do I grab only the month specification from the register at variable?

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(df$register_at, "\\s"), "[", 2))`

Comment: Is `register_at` really categorical or is it a date? or a string?

Comment: What do you get if you type `sapply(last.reg_data, class)`  ?

Comment: factors

sapply(last.reg_data, class) 
dsn registered_at 
     "factor"      "factor"

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$register_at), "\\s"), "[", 2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform the following steps:

1. Set up your locale to English (if your machine's locale is already English, you can skip this step!)
2. Use the as.Date function to format your data (Please check the format string below)
3. Once the data is in Date format, just extract the month part from the date.

Sample code:

```
#Create the data frame
mdata <- data.frame(dsn=character(0), register_at=character(0))
mdata <- edit(mdata)

#Set the locale to en_US (This is required, because month/date names are in english)
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_TIME", locale="English_US.1252")
Sys.getlocale()

#Convert the variable to date
mdata$register_at_date <- as.Date(mdata$register_at,format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y")

#Extract the month part
mdata$month <- months(mdata$register_at_date)

#Print out the data frame
print(mdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` function as `Month names` are always in the same possition.

```
substr(df$register_at, 5, 7)
```

Comment: It is working. My machine might having some trouble. I restarted both my PC and R and it's working perfect.

Thank you

Comment: @P.Nitu, please mark question as answered if it helped you or at least UP it.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I would try to get the dates written in a more standardized format, such as year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds.

However, I know that we may not always have control over the format of the data (boo). Just thought I'd mention that, if it was in a more standardized format, the `lubridate` package has a function called `floor_date` that would accomplish this easily.

For this specific instance, you could just split the string by a space and select only the second element after that split:

```
> # create data frame
> # note that, per your question, dsn and register_at are factors
> d <- data.frame(dsn=factor(c("AC000W000014612", "AC000W000016124", "AC000W000016219")),
+                 register_at=factor(c("Thu Mar 02 21:34:30 UTC 2017", "Tue Mar 14 19:40:57 UTC 2017", "Tue Apr 14 19:29:10 UTC 2017")))
> 
> library(stringr) # load package
> d$register_month <- str_split_fixed(as.character(d$register_at), " ", 3)[,2] # convert to character, split at a space, take the second element
> d
              dsn                  register_at register_month
1 AC000W000014612 Thu Mar 02 21:34:30 UTC 2017            Mar
2 AC000W000016124 Tue Mar 14 19:40:57 UTC 2017            Mar
3 AC000W000016219 Tue Apr 14 19:29:10 UTC 2017            Apr
```

Note that `register_month` will be a `character` vector, so if you want it as a factor, you'd have to also use `as.factor` to get it back to a factor.

Comment: I can't be sure without the data, but it seems like maybe one of the changes you are doing from `factor` to `character` is making everything `NA`? R gets fussy with factors sometimes.